# SaltStack result success only if return is expected

Tags: salt-stack

I'm using win_wua.list to check if the servers have available updates

```
update_system:
  module.run:
    - name: win_wua.list
```

The problem is that no meter if the server have pending updates or not the state result is "True"
But my goal is to run this as post-check so I want the state to be "successful" only if the return is "Nothing to return" in any other case I would like the state to be with result "False"

```
LKA5:
----------
          ID: update_system
    Function: module.run
        Name: win_wua.list
      Result: True
     Comment: Module function win_wua.list executed
     Started: 17:04:29.326587
    Duration: 4017.653 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              ret:
                  Nothing to return

Summary for LKA5
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:   4.018 s
LKA3:
----------
          ID: update_system
    Function: module.run
        Name: win_wua.list
      Result: True
     Comment: Module function win_wua.list executed
     Started: 17:04:25.563111
    Duration: 7113.497 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              ret:
                  Nothing to return

Summary for LKA3
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:   7.113 s
```

Comment: How are the updates managed? Outside of Saltstack?

Comment: Updates are managed by Salt with a runner, so to install them I'm using state with win_wua.list -- install=true in my orch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two modules to manage Windows updates with Saltstack:

- `win_wua` [execution module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_wua.html)
- `win_wua` [state module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.win_wua.html)

Seems you are using the execution module, which always runs irrespective of the current state of system. So it will always report as changed. On the other hand, the state module will only run if updates are required.

The following state ID will ensure that the system is updated (as specified), and it will report as changed. Then we can use the [requisite system](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) to trigger another state.

Example:

```yaml
# Including driver updates for example
update_system:
  wua.uptodate:
    - drivers: True

# Verify if further updates are there
verify_updates:
  module.run:
    - name: win_wua.list
    - install: True
    - onchanges:
        - wua: update_system
```

In the above example, if `update_system` didn't update anything (there were no updates), then `verify_updates` won't run. If some packages were updated, then `verify_updates` will run. There are other requisites (linked above) that can be considered as per your use case.

Comment: well in many cases you may have additional updates to install, they will show up only if the previous are installed

Comment: Well the point of using the state module is that it will either report a change (if updates exist), or not (when there are no updates). I will update the answer so that it is clearer.

Comment: For some reason, the state module always return "No updates found" even when i can see from guest OS that there are pending updates, I have tested it on 2012,2016 and 2019, if I'm using the execution module it's showing all updates that are in a pending state, no idea what I'm doing wrong ... master and minion version 3003

Comment: The state module has some flags to choose and skip updates on certain conditions. For example, any updates that require reboot are skipped by default. This can be changed with `skip_reboot: False`. Please refer to the documentation for the different criteria on which the updates can be installed or skipped.